# How to output a text's first line and last line to the terminal as a single command

Tags: bash

I have a text file named `test.txt` in current directory.now I want to output `test.txt`'s first line and its last line to the terminal with `cat text.txt | (head -1 ; tail -1)`, but the result is that it only outputs the first line to the terminal.

How do I output the first line and the last line using a single command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem with your command** is that **only the *1st* command - `head -1` - receives the stdin input**, because it *consumes* it on reading, so that the 2nd command - `tail -1` - receives *no input*.

In this particular case, you can **use *command grouping* (`{ ...; ...; }`)**:

```
{ head -1; tail -1; } < text.txt
```

*Caveats*:

- **The above only works with *seekable* input**, meaning either a **regular file**, a **here-string** or **here-doc**.

  - It will *not* work with pipeline input (`cat text.txt | { head -1; tail -1; }`) or with input from a [process substitutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`{ head -1; tail -1; } < <(cat text.txt)`), because such input is not seekable (`tail` cannot scan from the end backward).
- Even with seekable input this is *not* a generic method to send input to multiple commands at once.

  - The above only works because `tail` reads backwards from the *end* of the (seekable) input, irrespective of whether all the input has already been read or not.

---

As a **simpler alternative** that **works *generically***, here's a `sed` solution:

```
sed -n '1p; $p' text.txt
```

- `-n` suppresses output of lines by default
- `1p` matches line `1` and prints it (`p`).
- `$p` matches the last line (`$`) and prints it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use awk.

```
awk 'NR==1{print}END{print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tee`:

```
cat text.txt | tee >(head -1) >(tail -1) > /dev/null
```

Comment: Tempting, but, unfortunately, the sequencing of the output from the two process substitution cannot be guaranteed. On occasion, the last line will be printed _first_ (doesn't happen often, but it does happen).

Comment: Hm, that's quite true... though OP didn't say that they have to be in that order ☺

Comment: Have you considered a career in law?